# Cannot Get ImageButton onClick to fire

Tags: java, android, onclick, imagebutton

I have the following xmlFile:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.SPTechnos.ambassador.Home"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearBG"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ToolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#263359"
            android:gravity="top" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton_Back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton_Preferences"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton_Map"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mapmode" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="189dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_Speak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.79"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Which is matched with the following code in an oncreate

```
ImageButton speak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton_Speak);

speak.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*Toast.makeText(Home.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(!mIsListening)
                {
                    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent); // Listen
                    Log.d("OUTPUT", "Button Pressed");
                }*/
                Log.d("OUTPUT", "Button Pressed");
            }
        });
```

However, when I click the button nothing is printed to logcat, I have tried testing with Toasts and those two proved the onclick is no firing, I have searching for the past hour and could not find the cause.  IT must me something stupid I am overlooking...

Comment: You don't say where in the code you've setup this onClick listener.  Is it possible that it's not being called at all?  If you put a log message just before you call speak.setOnClickListener does that log message show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code and works. Check in your logCat if the device is connected.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageButton speak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton_Speak);

        speak.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "teste", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });     

    }

}
```

Comment: That worked and I saw the toast, but for some reason it is not printing to logcat...

Comment: I use genymotion emulator and for some reason my log was not displayed too when i checked logcat my device is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting clickable on your imageView you wish to click in XML

```
android:clickable="true"
```

or try in code

```
speak.setClickable(boolean)
```